# How to cut grid into cylinder without distortion?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to model my mic, the HyperX Quadcast, and I'm curious about how to create the red hexagonal grid bit as seen in this picture:

I have the hexagonal grid, however, I can't seem to figure out how to wrap it around the main cylinder shape without the grid getting distorted.

[image]

Anyways, I have a small .blend file that I made to test out ideas, I'll attach it if anyone wants to poke around.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender has a modifier for that :)

1. Add a *Simple deform Modifier* to your honeycomb
2. Set it to *Bend*, around Z axis
3. Adjust the *Angle*

Note: Your honeycomb is a bit messy, I'd suggest to use the one from *Extra Objects* addon instead.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Okay, I definitely tried that earlier, and it wasn't looking too nice... Yeah, the honeycomb thing I made earlier was from a different answer I saw on here. It was easy to follow, but the one in your answer is clearly cleaner. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, glad it works now :). Your grid was nicely procedural, but I couldn't make it work.